# Ternary operation or default value in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to perform ternary operation in bash (?:) where if variable is null provide default value.

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts l:m:ch:eh:cate:op:b flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
            l) localities=${OPTARG};;
            m) mode=${OPTARG};;
            ch) cbhost=${OPTARG};;
            eh) eshost=${OPTARG};;
            cate) category=${OPTARG};;
            op) outputDir=${OPTARG};;
            b) s3bucket=${OPTARG};;
    esac
done
```

out of all the variables, cbhost and eshost are optional variables.
how can in bash, i can check if null then assign default value using ternary operation?? or how can assign default values to each variable which can be overridden if arguments are passed.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up parameter expansion

Comment: did took a look on parameter expansion. will this work cbhost=${OPTARG:=hostvalue};;    I am not sure if this is accurate.

Comment: Just assign default values to them before parsing arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per `man getopt`

> `Optstring` is a string of **recognized option letters** (see getopt(3)); if a letter is followed by a colon, the option is expected to have an argument which may or may not be separated from it by white space.

So there are few issues:

1. You cannot use multi letter string as option. It has to be single letter only
2. It seems you are expecting an option value for `-b` option but that is not using a trailing `:`
3. You can set default value of each variable in a single for loop as shown below.

Here is suggested code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# set default value for these variables
declare localities='loc123' mode='m123' category='cat123' \
   outputDir='op123' s3bucket='s3123' cbhost='https://cbhost:1091/'

while getopts l:m:c:e:y:d:b: flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
            l) localities=${OPTARG};;
            m) mode=${OPTARG};;
            c) cbhost=${OPTARG};;
            e) eshost=${OPTARG};;
            y) category=${OPTARG};;
            d) outputDir=${OPTARG};;
            b) s3bucket=${OPTARG};;
    esac
done

# check values of your variables
declare -p localities mode category outputDir s3bucket cbhost eshost
```

Comment: thanks anubhava, for the corrections mentioned. i have doubt wrt default value. here, it seems you are assigning "default" word as default value to each variable. what if i want to have expected default values for few variables . like cbhost will have a http host and s3bucket will have bucket name. in that sense, will i have to explicitly set each variable??

Comment: I think that initial loop is overkill. A simple list of `declare var=default_value` declarations would suffice and be more understandable.

Comment: It could be just one too, but the point is that it would be more readable: `declare foo=aaa bar=bbb baz=ccc`. Put another way, we don't need `@` as a separator, we already have `=` :)

Comment: Fair point about readability. Answer edited.